# Capture only hour and minute from logs. Want to exclude seconds in output

Tags: shell, awk

I am running below command to capture output. In time section seconds are also getting captured. I want to exclude seconds in output. Please help

> cat /tmp/dnsmasq.log  | grep query | egrep -iv 'AAA|PTR|SRV' | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3","$8","$6}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {num=split($NF,arra
>   y,".");$NF=array[num-1]"."array[num]} 1'

Sample input file is below:

> May 31 17:58:57 dnsmasq[1695]: query[A] sites.google.com from 10.0.0.35
>
> May 31 17:59:15 dnsmasq[1695]: query[A] presence.teams.microsoft.com from 10.0.0.35

I want output like this:

> May 31 17:49,127.0.0.1,scotiabank.com
>
> May 31 17:49,10.0.0.35,google.com

Comment: If you want the sample input file and the desired output to be helpful, they should **match**. How do you get 17:49 in the output from the values you show in the input file? Where do you see scotiabank.com in your sample input file?

Comment: its sample input and output files to showcase the input / output file format. i dont think so it matters as values in these file will change in the input file. we need to create a generic command which will serve the purpose. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't. The sample output should be what would result from the sample input, following your business rules. For example, I would like to understand if 17:58:57 will be rounded to the closest minute (17:59) or truncated (17:58). This becomes obvious if your output matches the input; with what you posted, it's impossible to tell. Learn this as a very general rule, whenever you ask questions in computing (and, really, in any technical or even non-technical field).

Comment: again i will emphasize that it should not matter to focus on values. It should be the format of input and output files. I am aware of general rules and not at all novice in computing and technical field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution after seeing your Input_file but still not clear about conditions how to get it, try following once. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
/query/ && match($0,/^[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),$NF,$(NF-2)
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Since you have not shown your actual Input_file so following is written by seeing your shown command's output only.

```
your_command | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/:[0-9]{2}$/,"",$1)} 1'
```

IMHO you could do all these operations in a single `awk` itself if you show us the sample of  Input_file, rather than using 3 to 4 pipe commands.

***EDIT BY OP(Working command is):*** `cat /tmp/dnsmasq.log| grep query | egrep -iv 'AAA|PTR|SRV' | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3","$8","$6}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/:[0-9]{2}$/,"",$1)} 1' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {num=split($NF,array,".");$NF=array[num-1]"."array[num]} 1' |sort | uniq`

NOTE: This task could be done in a single `awk` but OP has added above commands into his/her existing code. For future users a single `awk` will be more efficient here.